# Flask WSGI application running out of memory

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a a fairly simple python Flask application running as a WSGI process under Apache2.
The application has a listener by using SQLAlchemy to retrieve a few lines of data from the DB and sending it back as a JSON

For the MySql connection I do have one global engine being reused.

Using JMeter to generate some load, the Apache2 process increase RAM usage by 0.5% units per every 5 second and very quickly running out of RAM. If stopping the JMeter generating the load the memory does not get cleared out.

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxxxxxxx.com

<Directory /var/www/xxxxxxxxxx>
    Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess BiddingPractice user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /flask /var/www/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/BiddingPractice>
    WSGIProcessGroup BiddingPractice
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**WSGI File**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/stefan/Code/xxxxxx')
from BiddingPractice import app as application
```

**_*init.py*_**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import *

app = Flask(__name__)
db = create_engine('mysql://root:xxxxxx@localhost/xxxxxxx')

import BiddingPractice.main
```

**main.py**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
from flask import jsonify
from BiddingPractice import app, db
from Data.users import getUsers
import random

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('temp.html', name=name)

@app.route('/getData')
def getData():

    un, psw, gids = getUsers()

    random.shuffle(un)
    random.shuffle(gids)

    usernames = ','.join(map(str, un))
    passwords = ','.join(map(str, psw))
    guids = ','.join(map(str, gids))

    return jsonify(usernames=usernames, passwords=passwords, guids=guids)
```

Anyone can tell if I have missed something or give me some tips on how to trouble shoot the memory usage, for example how could I see what is filling up the Apache2 process?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there any reason why you handle sqlalchemy on your own instead of using [`Flask-SQLAlchemy`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/)?

Comment: I have missed that one, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ThiefMaster That actually solved my problem! 250 requests per seconds and I'm not even over 1.5% RAM usage. I'm happy to give you the answer if you write one!

Comment: On bigger applications, it's much easier to use plain SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Flask-SQLAlchemy`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/). It takes care about proper handling of the connection and cleaning up things.

Besides that, it gives you lots of sugar such as `Modelclass.query` instead of `db.session.query(Modelclass)`

Answer (score 2):

You did not remove SQLAlchemy session object at the end of request. This should be done in `teardown_request` handler of your application (see example in Flask documentation). Flask-SQLAlchemy does this for you, but switching to Flask-SQLAlchemy is not required by far.